# Python->BeautifulSoup, get some text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erjqf.png) and i want to get the text part (labeled 'TEXT' in the linked image). How can I do this? I've tried combinations of `find, findAll` from `BeautifulSoup`, but I can't get it... I'm also using `Mechanize`. Things like that are not useful, I've a lot of classes here:

```
    h = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"one"})
    for tag in h:
        secondTags = tag.find_all("div", {"class":"two"})
        for tag in secondTags:
            print (tag.text)
```

Thanks!

P.S. I've deleted all ids and classes, sorry about that.

Edit:
The code is like:

```
<div class="main">
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="options">
        <ul id="select" class="u-select">
            <li class="generic" id="my">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>
                        <span class="header_arrow">...</span>
                        TEXT
                        <a class="info" href=" " </a>
                        <div class="tool_info" </div>
                    </h2>
```

Comment: post a sample html code here.

Comment: I've edited first post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to locate the `span` element with `header_arrow` class and then get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling).

Working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="options">
        <ul id="select" class="u-select">
            <li class="generic" id="my">
                <div class="header">
                    <h2>
                        <span class="header_arrow">...</span>
                        TEXT
                        <a class="info" href=" "> </a>
                        <div class="tool_info"> </div>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one("ul#select li.generic div.header h2 span.header_arrow").next_sibling.strip())
```

Prints:

```
TEXT
```